# Flashing the Code compatibility of STM32F767Zi processor to the STM32F746Tx

Tags: c, controller, embedded, stm32f7

I want to generate a code for STM32F767ZI but this MCU is not supported in the STM Motor Control workbench V5.4.8.

Available STM32F7 family MCUs in Workbench are STM32F746 and STM32F769.
I have generated code for the STM32F746 and flashed that code into STM32F767ZI but it is not working.

From some online help, it was found that both MCUs are the same and one can flash the code interchangeably into controllers.

Questions:
1- Is this possible to flash the code of STM32F746 into STM32F767ZI? If yes, why my code is not working even though I flashed the code into STM32F767ZI, still, I am still unable to build a communication between the Monitor window of Workbench. The COM port is not detecting.

2- if not possible, then should I have to buy a supported microcontroller?

Thanks and Regards

I tried to flash the STM32F746 motor control firmware to the STM767ZI. Code build successfully and also upload but UART commuincation is not working.

Comment: There are many possible ways they may be incomparable.  If the PLL/Click tree is not compatible it is unlikely to even start up.  I am not familiar with Motor Control Workbench, but no doubt it will be possible to fix-up any generated code to retarget it.  That said motor control will no doubt make extensive use of the PWM timer functions, and that may be another incomparability. Check the datasheet/user manual that the peripherals are available and identical.